# Como eu crio 2 forms simultaneamente Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.8

O que eu quero é em um único templante trazer estes 2 forms simultaneamente, em páginas separadas funciona, mas os dois juntos ainda não consegui fazer. Preciso fazer um form intermediário? Estou fazendo errado algum ponto?

... forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import *


class IdiomaForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Idioma
        fields = '__all__'


class LinguagemForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Linguagem
        fields = '__all__'
```

.... views.py

```
def Idioma(request):
    form = IdiomaForm()
    return render(request, 'curriculo/idioma.html', {'form': form})
```

.... idioma.html

{

```
% extends 'curriculo/base.html' %}
{% block content %}

    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Salvar">
    </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O contexto passado para a função render é um dicionário, você pode passar quantos argumentos quiser e com o nome que lhe convêm.
Por exemplo:

```
def Idioma(request):
    form_idioma = IdiomaForm()
    form_ling = LinguagemForm()
    return render(request, 'curriculo/idioma.html', {'form1': form_idioma, 'form2': form_ling})
```

Desse jeito você pode ter dois formulários no mesmo template, acessando cada um pelo nome que você definiu no contexto:

```
{% extends 'curriculo/base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form1 }}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Salvar Idioma">
</form>
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form2 }}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Salvar Lingua">
</form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Obrigado, acho que não havia entendido direito o funcionamento de um dicionário. Obrigado novamente